# capture regex pattern of exactly n characters ignoring longer groups in r

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract isotope numbers from a file name. The numbers I am looking for are 223 and 224. But these might occur multiple times in the filename, especially as part of a date. How can I capture 223 or 224 (or any 3-character string) and ignore them if they are part of a longer number string?

I've tried these and a few more but no luck.

```
sub(".*(223|224).*", "\\1", "St1_224standard_20200223")
sub(".*([223|224]{3}).*", "\\1", "St1_224standard_20200223")
sub(".*([2|3|4]{3}).*", "\\1", "St1_224standard_20200223")
```

I always get `223` when what I want is `224`.
I know I can make the targeted number the last one in the string, but I have no influence on the file names used by others.
Thanks

Comment: bookend your capture group with "is not numeric" - regex for that is I think `[^$0-9.]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
sub(".*?(?<!\\d)(22[34])(?!\\d).*", "\\1", "St1_224standard_20200223", perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/9Efi9G).

There are several key points here:

- `.*?` is used at the start to match the least amount of chars necessary to get to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `(?<!\d)` / `(?!\d)` are a pair of lookbehind and lookahead that define the numeric boundaries
- `perl=TRUE` makes it all work since the pattern is a PCRE-compliant pattern (the default TRE engine does not support lookarounds).

Note I condensed `223|224` into `22[34]` that is just a bit shorter and more efficient.

See the [regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/ttvBV1/1), too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain why I need the first `?`, and not use `sub(".*(?<!\\d)(22[34])(?!\\d).*", "\\1", "St1_224standard_20200223", perl=TRUE)`?

Comment: @DavidKaiser I surmised you wanted to get the first, not last, match.